# Lead form that submits to 2 external APIs

Tags: plugin-development, forms, api

I need to add 2 registration forms to my wp website, each form should submit the information in it to 2 different APIs.

I don't know even where to begin. Is there a plugin that can help me handle the task? do i need to write a plugin from scratch?

any pointer or recommendation will be much appreciated as i'm totally in the dark here.

EDIT: Add more info as requested by UBERABUSER (thanks!)

The 2 APIs i'm working with are 
(a) client CRM, a custom API written in perl, handles registration of prospective clients
(b) An API of a list management / mailing service called TRACTION

Here's a working example of such a form: http://benchmarketing.com.au/k2a/ebook/

Now i need to create a version of the same form with the exact same functionality in wordpress... and this is what i'm in the dark about.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use a plugin to handle to creation and management of your forms or whether you create and maintain your forms manually, its pretty safe to say that any interaction with external APIs will require some custom coding in order to inter-operate with those APIs.

We're also **totally in the dark on this question too** because you haven't said what these APIs are/or who they belong to and what kind of data is being submitted and in what formats you are required to work with.

There is always a chance someone has created a plugin that makes interfacing with your external APIs but that's usually for the more popular ones.

...so, we need more info!

Comment: @Talbatz That's shows the form fields you need but doesn't tell us much about the API requirements. The APIs will specify how they want the data received, REST/SOAP/JSON and will also specify the kind of response values returned. Unless you need to do something else with the data that you are submitting externally, with WordPress itself, this is not really a WordPress based question, more of a general html/php/API question suited for StackOverflow - but I'll still help you... Just need some real info to work with mate.

Comment: Come to [chat]...